# How to make a leaderboard ranking scores JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Currently, my code shows the score of the user that's logged in. I want to show the highest score obtained by each user on the leaderboard until the top 10.

js from index.html

```
<script> 
        loadRankingTable();
        window.onload = () => {
  //Check login
        if (sessionStorage.loggedInUser !== undefined) {
        let oldData = localStorage.getItem(sessionStorage.loggedInUser);
        console.log(JSON.parse(oldData))
        if (oldData) {
            oldData = JSON.parse(oldData);
            oldData.topScore = highscore;
            localStorage.setItem(sessionStorage.loggedInUser, JSON.stringify(oldData));
    }
        document.getElementById("Greeting").innerHTML = sessionStorage.loggedInUser;
  }
}

        </script>
```

prac.js

```
function loadRankingTable(){
    let str = "<table><tr><th>Rank</th><th>Name</th><th>Score</th></tr>";
    for(let key of Object.keys(localStorage)){
        let usr = JSON.parse(localStorage[key]);
        str += "<tr><td>" + "1" + "</td><td>" + sessionStorage.loggedInUser + "</td><td>" + highscore + "</td></tr>";
    }
    str += "</table>";
    document.getElementById("Ranking").innerHTML = str;
}
```

The highscore gets stored in the local storage, but I want the logged in user's highscore shown next to their name on the leaderboard, up till the top 10.

Comment: You forgot to use `key` and `usr` instead of `sessionStorage.loggedInUser` and `highscore` in `loadRankingTable()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: (others have permission to copy and edit this)

```js
function load(){
  var userscores = {
    "ex1": 10,
    "noncy": 40,
    "del3tus": 24,
    "the_r0ck": 8,
    "MONSTER_OSITY": 120
  };
  var max = 0;
  var sorted = [];
  for(var prop in userscores){
    if(userscores[prop] >= max){
      max = userscores[prop];
    }
  }
  var cur = max;
  for(var i = max; i > 0; i--){
    for(var prop in userscores){
      if(userscores[prop] == i){
        sorted.push(prop);
      }
    }
  }
  var html = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++){
    html = "<tr><td>" + (i + 1) + "</td><td>" + sorted[i] + "</td><td>" + userscores[sorted[i]] + "</td></tr>";
    document.getElementById("leaderboard").innerHTML += html;
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="load();">Load leaderboard</button>
<table id="leaderboard" border="1" cellSpacing="0px"><tr><th>#</th><th>Name</th><th>Points</th></tr></table>
```

If that doesn't work, let me know. You can also change it to make it fit better.